# Android horizontal scroll and horizontal flip

Tags: android, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, flip

I have a webview, in which I load images.

When I zoom in, I want users to scroll to view the rest of the contents. But when I scroll horizontally, horizontal flip is getting triggered.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

This blog is very usefull in the matter: [Preserving screen state in WebView](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/). It works even for JavaScript variables etc..